# Elasticsearch bool must_not doesn't work with multi-fields.

Tags: elasticsearch

I use multi-fields https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html

Here is part of my mapping:

```
...
"Diagnosis": {
               "type": "string",
               "fields":{
                 "not_analyzed":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "index":"not_analyzed"
                 }
                }
            }
...
```

I run this query:

```
curl -XGET 'elasticsearch_server:9200/db-index/Diagnosis/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"bool": {"must_not": [{"match": {"Diagnosis.not_analyzed": "F06.4 - Organic anxiety disorder"}}], "must": [{"match": {"Diagnosis": "Dementia disease disorder"}}]}}}'
```

Despite the must_not clause the query above returns "**F06.4 - Organic anxiety disorder**" string amid other results.

I can exclude all results with 'anxiety' word doing this

```
curl -XGET 'elasticsearch_server:9200/db-index/Diagnosis/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"bool": {"must_not": [{"match": {"Diagnosis": "anxiety"}}], "must": [{"match": {"Diagnosis": "Dementia disease disorder"}}]}}}'
```

But the goal is to exclude only the exact string "**F06.4 - Organic anxiety disorder**" from results.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
1)  Change the mapping to lower case the data but don't cut them by word  (default mapping )

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/...../' -d '{
 "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "keylower":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
        "specimens" : {
            "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
            "_index" : {"enabled" : true},
            "_id" : {"index": "not_analyzed", "store" : false},
            "properties" : {

                "Diagnosis" : {"type" : "string",   "store" : "yes","index": "not_analyzed" } 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) this will return only data not containing "*Organic anxiety disorder*" (where `*` can be any words)

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : [{
                    "wildcard" : {
                        "Diagnosis" : {
                            "value" : "*organic anxiety disorder*"
                        }
                    }

                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

3) use a strict search to exclude data :

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : [{
                    "term" : {
                        "Diagnosis.not_analyzed" : "f06.4 - organic anxiety disorder"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried both your examples, and they return "F06.4 - Organic anxiety disorder".

Comment: i think it come from the mapping. can you try with lower case ?

Comment: the second query work for me. i think you should change the mapping to lower case the case on some field to avoid error

Comment: i change the answer and add a new mapping to lower case the data. then use a lowercase string in query to avoid problem with lower/upper case

Comment: I see, in the mapping you use only one field Diagnosis and it is not_analyzed. But I need to use multi-fields to be able to query both analyzed and not_analyzed variants of a particular string type field. Also, I don't have lowercase only data in my index.

Comment: Resolved! There was an extra space after the dash in the string: "f06.4 -  organic anxiety disorder". I added it and now must_not works with both "term" and "match". Wildcard also works with the following syntax: [{"wildcard": {"Diagnosis.not_analyzed": {"value": "*F06.4 -  Organic anxiety disorder*"}}}]. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I can't vote for your answer right now because my rank on stackoverflow is too low yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude exact String use `term query` like .

```
curl -XGET 'elasticsearch_server:9200/db-index/Diagnosis/_search? pretty' -d '{"query": {"bool": {"must_not": [{"term": {"Diagnosis.not_analyzed": "F06.4 - Organic anxiety disorder"}}], "must": [{"match": {"Diagnosis": "Dementia disease disorder"}}]}}}'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried your example, and it returns "F06.4 - Organic anxiety disorder".